# Service Fabric Cluster creation fails on Azure with error code "VMInstanceCountAllowsBetterReliabilityLevel"

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

When trying to create a Service Fabric Cluster with the Silver reliability level on Azure I get the "VMInstanceCountAllowsBetterReliabilityLevel" error code and the following message -

> Primary NodeTypes {TestType:10} has 10 vm instances. Please use
>   reliability level Platinum.

Has anyone encountered this error? Is there a way to use the Silver reliability level with this many Primary nodes?

According to the documentation there is a minimum number of nodes per Reliability Level but I couldn't find anything that mentions a maximal number of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today there is no good way to run a lower reliability level when you have enough nodes for a higher reliability level. There's no real "maximum" number of nodes for a given reliability level. However the system is trying to enforce best practices: since you have more nodes, it makes sense to run more copies of the system services and seed nodes, so that the overall cluster is more available and reliable. There's not a lot of overhead to doing so, so it defaults to this behavior. We will update the docs to make this more clear.

Comment: How about a warning and not an error? There are legitimate reasons to create a cluster with a lower reliability level - eg I'm temporarily creating the cluster with more nodes than I need for upgrade behavior or load handling, and I will reduce the cluster size later.

To put it another way - if there were no good reason to have a reliabilityLevel setting separate from node count, then the reliabilityLevel parameter should be removed.

Comment: The goal is to do exactly that and have the reliability tier automatically calculated based on the size of the cluster. It's a fair request to make this a warning however the current error was added to enforce best practices as until then we had the opposite problem of people creating large clusters and expecting a more reliable experience and not getting it. Hopefully this is reasonable and we can get to the automated behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In this documents, you can see limits and scalings nodes.

Limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity

Scaling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down

I hope these documents can help you. 
Regards.

Comment: Hi Gaston, Thank you for answering. Can you paste the relevant parts in the attached link which is related to the question in play

Comment: Thanks @Gastón but as far as I could tell from the documentation these are only the limits for minimum number of nodes, whereas what I'm seeing is a problem with the maximum number of nodes.